# Windows10 - How to force login to network share (adminshare)?

Tags: windows-10, networking, security-policy

I come to you with a topic of forcing login to other PC where somebody wants to access C$ (adminshare).

I have situation that everybody in domain are able to access my \localhost\C$ without providing any access data, I tried to find out some security policy rule for that but unfortunately I can't find it out.

Is there anybody who faced such a problem and is able to guide me how to force credential prompt for that purpose?

Comment: Ask your IT administrator how to secure your machine properly.

Comment: This is not a solution my friend.

Comment: It is the only solution, so yes, it is a solution. Your pc is very insecure, anyone can hack anyone's pc. If you can find out the computername of your IT, you can hack them, delete files and make them comply.

Comment: ... unless you altered security settings yourself and now you need to stop this and you don't want them to find out. In that case you are on your own.

Comment: It's possible to disable totally the creation of all administrative shares (look for `AutoShareWks`). However, the domain administrators might be unhappy with this.

Answer (score 0):

The administrative shares (C$, ADMIN$, etc.) are accessible by everyone who is a **member of the local "Administrators" group** on the destination machine. As far as I know, this cannot be changed anywhere.

So it sounds like someone has added the "Domain Users" AD group to the local Administrators group, or something similar. Run `lusrmgr.msc` on the problematic machine and check *Groups → Administrators* to see who's a member of that group. (Alternatively, `Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators` via PowerShell.)

Remember that local group members can be deployed through Group Policy – use `gpresult` to check which GPOs affect your system. If you find something suspicious and you're not a domain administrator yourself, you should talk to someone who is.

---

Note: Don't confuse authentication ("forcing login") with authorization (gaining access). In an Active Directory domain environment, it is normal that any user will be able to *authenticate* to your system with their domain credentials – that's completely different from them getting actual *access* to the system. In AD, the expected result is that they'll just get an "Access Denied" error message, but they will *not* get a credential prompt.